# Do all IPv4-compatible IPv6 devices have two IPv6 addresses?

Tags: networking, ipv6

Is it possible for an IPv4-compatible IPv6 device to have only one IPv6 address?

For example, when device-A talks to an IPv4 device, device-A communicates using its IPv4 address 2.2.2.4. Later, when device-A talks to an IPv6 device, can it use its IPv6 address ::2.2.2.4?

Or must all IPv4-compatible IPv6 device have two IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Why are you saying it must have two IPv6 addresses? In your example what will be the two addresses?

Comment: @criziot Since device-A can't talk to IPv6 devices using his address ::2.2.2.4 (reserved IPv6 address), he needs to use another IPv6 address to talk to IPv6 devices right?

Comment: Ok. I got it. But as @Sander Steffann said, ::2.2.2.4 isn't used anymore. You usually have an autoconfigured IPv6 for link local and eventually a global address if you have an IPv6 capable router. But none of those are related with the IPv4 address you may have.

Comment: @criziot So before automatic tunneling was deprecated, each IPv4-compatible IPv6 device has 1 IPv4 address + 2 IPv6 addresses = 3 address per device?

Comment: Yes. You allays need a link local address, and if you want to communicate with a machine in other network you will need a global address since link local addresses are only valid within the link. So 2 IPv6 plus the IPv4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

::2.2.2.4 is not a valid address to use. It was once intended for automatic tunnelling (see the old [RFC 3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513#section-2.5.5)) but these days it is not used anymore (they became obsolete in [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5)).

There is another IPv6 address format called IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses. The look like ::ffff:2.2.2.4 and they are used in IPv6 software that runs on an IPv4 compatible host. For example: Linux supports IPv4 connections on IPv6 sockets. So if a server is written to use IPv6 it can still accept incoming connections over IPv4. Because the server software expects IPv6 addresses the IPv4 addresses are represented as IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses. That doesn't mean that you are communicating with IPv6 though. It means that IPv6 compatible software is communicating with IPv4.

To answer your question: If you want to communicate dual-stack (with both IPv4 and IPv6) then you need at least two addresses: one IPv4 address and one IPv6 address. Both need to be routed on the internet. The IPv6 addresses currently in use on the Internet come from the 2000::/3 prefix (everything starting with 2000: to 3fff:) so you'll need those.

Comment: Before automatic tunneling was deprecated, how many IPv6 addresses does a IPv4-compatible IPv6 device have?

Comment: The amount of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses depends on how the device is configured. A common configuration is one IPv4 address, a link-local IPv6 address and an auto-configured global IPv6 address based on the MAC address of the network adapter. Another common configuration is one IPv4 address, a link-local IPv6 address, an auto-configured global IPv6 address based on the MAC address of the network adapter and multiple auto-configured global IPv6 addresses based on the IPv6 privacy extensions.

Comment: Ic, just to confirm, before automatic tunneling was deprecated, is it valid for a device to use the address `::2.2.2.4` as its global IPv6 address?

Comment: Yes, see (now obsolete) [RFC 2893](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2893#section-5.2)

Comment: Ic, so you are disagreeing with criziot http://superuser.com/questions/448267/do-all-ipv4-compatible-ipv6-devices-have-two-ipv6-addresses/448269#comment-520845? He said IPv4 compatible IPv6 address has minimum of 2 IPv6 addresses, but actually it is valid for a IPv4 compatible IPv6 address device to have only one IPv6 address?

Comment: Critiot is not talking about IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses. He says you need at least a link-local address for IPv6, which lets you communicate on the local link (usually ethernet) only. If you want to communicate beyond that you need a global address as well. Please forget about IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses. They are not relevant.